# NOW() and CURDATE() on MySQL returns different format on C#

Tags: c#, mysql, win-universal-app, uwp

On MySQL Workbench:

```
SELECT NOW()     -> '2016-08-24 21:26:12'
SELECT CURDATE() -> '2016-08-24'
```

This is the desired result, however on my UWP app written in C#:

```
public static string CurrentDate()
{
    using (var connection = OpenConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT CURDATE();";
        string date = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        connection.Close();
        return date;
    }
}

public static string Now()
{
    using (var connection = OpenConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT NOW();";
        string date = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        connection.Close();
        return date;
    }
}

Now()         -> '24-Aug-16 9:26:12 PM'
CurrentDate() -> '24-Aug-16 12:00:00 AM'
```

Does this have anything to do with local time settings on my computer? How can I ensure the result will be the same as in my MySQL Workbench?

Comment: the results are logically the same.  Just parse as a datetime in C#, and return whatever string format you want.

Comment: but then I need to know if the result are the same on different PCs with different time format settings

Comment: A date doesn't have formatting information, only date information.  Every client displaying a date is free to format it the way it wants to if you don't specify a specific format.  If you want to enforce a specific format, then have your query return a string with the desired format instead of a date.  That said, I have a hard time understand why you need the formatting to match in this case.  I suspect you are thinking about the problem the wrong way.

Comment: If you just want the date, return `yourdateTime.Date()`. The timestamp you get is an integral part of a date**time** so it is initialized to 00 hours, 00 minutes and 00 seconds.

Comment: but they are completely different - CURDATe() after date format will be 00:00:00, but NOW() has a complete different time. Try `CONCAT_WS(' ', CURDATE(), CURTIME())` if you wanna same results